# SQL Server 2016 не устанавливается

Tags: sql-server, сервер, install

Скачал с сайта Microsoft **SQL Server 2016 Express**. Выбрал пункт **Базовая** установка. Вышла вот такая вещь.

[image: Окно с ошибкой]

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, что делать. Двое суток уже вожусь, не могу никак установить...

Comment: Предлагаю посмотреть детальную информацию об ошибке в журнале установки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может у вас была установлена старая версия MS SQL? Зайдите в установку и удаление программ и проверьте. Установку запускаете от имени Администратора? Подробные причины нужно смотреть в логе установщика.

Comment: да, была установлена версия 2012. Но при попытке удалить её элементы, появлялось окно, что невозможно найти файл-установщик.

Comment: В такой ситуации есть несколько вариантов
1. Заново установить MSSQL 2012 и затем удалить его
2. Пробовать утилитой Windows Installer CleanUp Utility почистить следы установки 
3. В ручную чистить все следы пребывания ms sql (каталоги, реестр)